# Select rows where at least one value from the list of columns is not null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe with many columns (like 1000). I have a list of columns (generated by a script ~10). And I would like to select all the rows in the original dataframe where at least one of my list of columns is not null.

So if I would know the number of my columns in advance, I could do something like this:

```
list_of_cols = ['col1', ...]
df[
  df[list_of_cols[0]].notnull() |
  df[list_of_cols[1]].notnull() |
  ...
  df[list_of_cols[6]].notnull() |
]
```

I can also iterate over the list of cols and create a mask which then I would apply to `df`, but his looks too tedious. Knowing how powerful is pandas with respect to dealing with nan, I would expect that there is a way easier way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `thresh` parameter in the `dropna()` method.  By setting `thresh=1`, you specify that if there is at least 1 non null item, don't drop it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((1., np.nan), (1000, 1000), p=(.3, .7)))
list_of_cols = list(range(10))

df[list_of_cols].dropna(thresh=1).head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting with this:

```
data = {'a' :      [np.nan,0,0,0,0,0,np.nan,0,0,  0,0,0,    9,9,],
    'b' :      [np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,    1,7],
    'c' :      [np.nan,np.nan,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,  1,1,1,    1,1],
    'd' :      [np.nan,np.nan,7,9,6,9,7,np.nan,6,  6,7,6,    9,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df
      a    b    c    d
0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   0.0  1.0  1.0  7.0
3   0.0  1.0  1.0  9.0
4   0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0
5   0.0  1.0  2.0  9.0
6   NaN  1.0  3.0  7.0
7   0.0  1.0  3.0  NaN
8   0.0  1.0  3.0  6.0
9   0.0  2.0  1.0  6.0
10  0.0  2.0  1.0  7.0
11  0.0  2.0  1.0  6.0
12  9.0  1.0  1.0  9.0
13  9.0  7.0  1.0  6.0
```

Rows where not all values are nulls. (Removing row index 0)

```
df[~df.isnull().all(axis=1)]

      a    b    c    d
1   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   0.0  1.0  1.0  7.0
3   0.0  1.0  1.0  9.0
4   0.0  1.0  2.0  6.0
5   0.0  1.0  2.0  9.0
6   NaN  1.0  3.0  7.0
7   0.0  1.0  3.0  NaN
8   0.0  1.0  3.0  6.0
9   0.0  2.0  1.0  6.0
10  0.0  2.0  1.0  7.0
11  0.0  2.0  1.0  6.0
12  9.0  1.0  1.0  9.0
13  9.0  7.0  1.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
df[~pd.isnull(df[list_of_cols]).all(axis=1)]
```

**Explanation:**

The expression `df[list_of_cols]).all(axis=1)` returns a boolean array that is applied as a filter to the dataframe:

- [`isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) applied to `df[list_of_cols]` creates a boolean mask for the dataframe `df[list_of_cols]` with `True` values for the null elements in `df[list_of_cols]`, `False` otherwise
- [`all()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) returns `True` if all of the elements are `True` (row-wise `axis=1`)

So, by negation `~` (not all null = at least one is non-null) one gets a mask for all rows that have at least one non-null element in the given list of columns.

**An example:**

Dataframe:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[11,22,33,np.NaN],
                     'B':['x',np.NaN,np.NaN,'w'],
                     'C':['2016-03-13',np.NaN,'2016-03-14','2016-03-15']})
>>> df
    A    B           C
0  11    x  2016-03-13
1  22  NaN         NaN
2  33  NaN  2016-03-14
3 NaN    w  2016-03-15
```

`isnull` mask:

```
>>> ~pd.isnull(df[list_of_cols])
       B      C
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False   True
3   True   True
```

apply `all(axis=1)` row-wise:

```
>>> ~pd.isnull(df[list_of_cols]).all(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Boolean selection from dataframe:

```
>>> df[~pd.isnull(df[list_of_cols]).all(axis=1)]
    A    B           C
0  11    x  2016-03-13
2  33  NaN  2016-03-14
3 NaN    w  2016-03-15
```

Comment: How could I employ this not to look for null, but to count instances of a specific value?

For example, given a dataframe with 10 columns, I want to count the number of rows where the value in five of those columns is "Missing/Incomplete".

I have found dozens of threads on how to count ALL the values in each row or column, but I only want a count where the value matches this string exactly.